# Вывод сообщений mongod

Tags: python, python-3.x, mongodb, subprocess

Есть скрипт на Python для запуска Mongodb

```
import subprocess

proc = subprocess.Popen("mongod", shell=False, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

out = proc.stdout.readlines()
for line in out:
    print(line)
```

Запускаю в консоли скрипт starter.py:

```
python starter.py
```

Mongod запускается, но ничего в консоли не выводится. Почему и как сделать чтобы выводилось что-то, как если бы мы напрямую запускали в консоли mongod.exe?

Answer (score 1):

попробуйте так:

```
output = subprocess.check_output("mongod", shell=False)
```